# App not functioning the same on 32 bit devices - NSInteger vs intValue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, nsmutablearray

I noticed after increasing the number of arrays that are instantiated into memory from 8 to 23, my app just stops running

```
[NSMutableArray addObject:obj]
```

on the 13th array on 32 bit devices only.  On an iPad Air 2 (device and sim) and iPhone 6 (device and sim) all 23 arrays are populated and the app functions as expected.

I understand there's a point at which a device will run out of available memory, and I noticed in Xcode on a 32 bit device, the app memory was hovering around **50-55mb**, but the app doesn't crash or give a memory warning in the console.  On a 64 bit device or sim, at the same point of interest, the app memory is around **90-95mb**?

1) how is memory for 32 bit devices different from 64 bit devices when it comes to the amount of data that can be instantiated?

2) is there a certain number of arrays that can be init to memory unrelated to the size, considering I could populate 2 out of 23 arrays with a single small object and the first would have the right count and the 2nd (any array with an ID > 13) would be 0 like this?

```
    if (obj.eventTypeID == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]) {obj.color = [UIColor whiteColor];[array1 addObject:obj];}
//ALL ARRAYS ALWAYS POPULATE NO MATTER THE COUNT OR SIZE BETWEEN 1 AND 13
    if (obj.eventTypeID == [NSNumber numberWithInt:13]) {obj.color = [UIColor greenColor];[array13 addObject:obj];}
//ALL ARRAYS ARE ALWAYS EMPTY BETWEEN 14 AND 23
    if (obj.eventTypeID == [NSNumber numberWithInt:23]) {obj.color = [UIColor redColor];[array23 addObject:obj];}
```

Hopefully that's enough to go on.  Just remember, the app works as expected on 64 bit, but not in 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I ended up fixing the problem by casting the conditional statements using intValue...genius, I know...

```
if ([obj.eventTypeID intValue] == 1)
```

Although this solved a huge bug, I still don't understand why the precision of doing it the other way is any different.

> obj.eventTypeID is an NSInteger

So why is this any different?  More importantly, why is this difference powerful enough to stop the thread from processing these conditions inside a loop if it's not an intValue?  These are some of the unanswered parts of this question, but it's long been solved with the solution above.