# iOS 9: Black Background on buttons, and performance errors on some devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-plot

We have a case where 3 of 4 iPads run our app as expected, then on the one that isn't loading a large array of (x,y) points on a graph, the only difference from screenshots are black backgrounds on the "< Back" button in the nav.  It also looks like the old back button on iOS 5 and 6? (**UPDATE: Read comment by rmaddy about "Button Shapes" setting in General > Accessibility**)

[image] VS [image]

> Version is 9.0.2(13A452), Wi-Fi only, and Model is
>   MD510LL/A

VS.

> Version is 9.0.2(13A452), Carrier is Verizon 21.1 and Model is
>   MD524LL/A

The black button one is an iPad 4th gen running iOS 9 and there's old school black backgrounds on that device only?  I changed the window.tintColor to black to fix a UIAlertAction bug where white text was unreadable, so maybe that explains part of this?

**Graphing Issue**

The main concern is when loading a core plot graph, all the x values are staying at zero during an time interval increment loop **on a small percentage of devices**.  I've seen 32bit devices fail at doing this before, and the 4th gen is 32bit.  HOWEVER...I personally have tested an iPad 4th gen with the same specs as the second one above.

Everything works as expected on my test device...as far as the differences of Wi-Fi only, Verizon/ATT, and all the 32bit/64bit explanations of these issues I found this helpful: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/ipad-air-faq/differences-between-ipad-air-ipad-4th-gen.html

Are some of the new settings in iOS 9 like "Low Power Mode" going to affect the ability to network using a Verizon data plan when wifi isn't available?  That's the current situation, including the devices in question being on a VPN.

**Again, these are two different devices running the same app!**  The one with the black background has issues loading the graph data.  Is there a new setting in iOS 9 that would cause these strange differences/errors from device to device?

NOTE: recently found out that one user's iPhone 6s+ is having the same graphing error, so it's not just iPad related...

Here's how the (x,y) coords are populated from SOAP response object:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];

if (unitCount == 0)
    {
        DataHistory_object *dho = [[DataHistory_object alloc] init];
        dho.dataDate = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Date"];
        NSLog(@"dho.dataDate: %@",dho.dataDate);
        dho.dataValue = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Value"];
        float dataValue = [dho.dataValue floatValue];

        newDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dho.dataDate];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dho.dataDate forKey:@"firstDate"];

        //@"start" is defined in a separate class
        if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"start"] isEqualToString:dho.dataDate])
        {
            NSDate *start = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"start"]];
            firstDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dho.dataDate];
            NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
            interval = secondsBetween;
            NSString *startDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:newDate]];
            NSLog(@"firstDate: %@",startDate);
            NSLog(@"unitCount == 0 if: %d - interval: %f",unitCount,interval);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"unitCount == 0 else: %d - interval: %f",unitCount,interval);
        }

        if (trendIndex == 0)
        {
            [dataHistoryArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 1) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray2 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 2) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray3 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 3) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray4 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 4) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray5 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 5) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray6 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 6) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray7 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }

        oldDate = newDate;

        unitCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        DataHistory_object *dho = [[DataHistory_object alloc] init];
        dho.dataDate = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Date"];
        dho.dataValue = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Value"];
        float dataValue = [dho.dataValue floatValue];

        newDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dho.dataDate];

        NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [newDate timeIntervalSinceDate:oldDate];
        interval = (interval + secondsBetween);
        NSLog(@"unitCount %d - interval: %f",unitCount,interval);

        if (trendIndex == 0) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 1)
        {
            [dataHistoryArray2 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 2) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray3 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 3) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray4 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 4) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray5 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 5) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray6 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }
        if (trendIndex == 6) 
        {
            [dataHistoryArray7 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:interval],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dataValue],@"y",nil]];
        }

        oldDate = newDate;

        unitCount++;

    }
```

Here's how the arrays are loaded:

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {

if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"Blue"])
{
    return [dataHistoryArray count];
}
//...same code for other arrays and colors    

return 0;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

NSNumber *num;

if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"Blue"])
{
    num = [[dataHistoryArray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")];
    return num;
}
//...same for other arrays and colors

return 0;
}
```

I also need to manipulate the graph after each plot is added:

```
-(void)changePlotRange {
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(appDelegate.lowY);
    plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"secondsBetween"])];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(appDelegate.lowY) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(appDelegate.highY-appDelegate.lowY)];
}
```

Comment: The device with the black button has enabled the "Button Shapes" option under General -> Accessibility in the Settings app. This was added in iOS 7.

Comment: @rmaddy great stuff...that was a tough google, so thanks to the rmaddy search engine.  How about the data loss issue?  Just got word that his iPad has charging issues and might be defective?  Would that cause a certain amount of processing to happen until the app stops SOAP calls and or large dictionary creating for loops?  Here's a related SO post with Q&A on 32bit vs 64bit oddities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193731/app-not-functioning-the-same-on-32-bit-devices-nsinteger-vs-intvalue

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the way the data is loaded. Is it downloaded over the network or from a local source like Core Data? If the graph is drawn before the dataset is available to the app, does the app have a callback or notification handler that calls `-reloadData` on the graph when the new data becomes available?

Comment: @EricSkroch it's from a web service SOAP call, and yes, there a multiple calls to reloadData.  It's really about why 3 out of 4 users don't experience the graphing error...and even when I'm testing on the user's server, I can't reproduce the error, so I'm starting to thing it's related to date formatting errors due to time zones and user location, but we only starting seeing the error recently, with iOS 9 so....the x values are related to seconds, so if the loop through has all x values as "0" the plots are "scrunched" at the origin but the y values are all correct.

Comment: Can you post your data loading and graphing code? It's hard to troubleshoot specific problems when we can't see the code.

Comment: I posted the code in question @EricSkroch ... I actually don't have a reloadData that's called. Only multiple [graph addPlot:bluePlot]; type calls for each color that's toggled from a custom menu. The thing I'm trying to focus on is that the most devices are loading the intervals as the x coordinate correctly and two reported devices out of hundreds (one iPad 4th gen, and one iPhone 6s+) aren't, even though it's the same date/value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realizing this wasn't the easiest question to have an accepted answer, I will update this post with what I found out.

**The plotting issue where some users were reporting all the data scrunched to the left of the graph was due to those users running in MILITARY TIME**.  My interval calculations using NSDateFormatter never took this into account.  I ended up making a category for NSDateFormatter that handles dates the way the existing code expects no matter the date format.

As for the difference in button color, that was answered by Rick Maddy in a comment so I wasn't able to accept his answer:

> **The device with the black button has enabled the "Button Shapes" option under General => Accessibility in the Settings app. This was added in iOS 7.**

Answer (score 1):

When is the `secondsBetween` default value set? There might be timing issues on some devices that cause the app to retrieve the wrong value.

You could also use `[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]]` to recompute the plot space ranges after you add new data to any of the plots.

Comment: Are you referring to CPTDecimalFromFloat([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"secondsBetween"]?  If you are it happens before the graph is even added, and before the NSURLConnection that loads the data into the dictionary.  This value also changes when a user used the datePicker to change the date range.  I don't use scaleToFit all plots because some plots won't have data to fill the date range...not to say you're not on to something...I just don't have a way to reproduce this since the same device specs have been tested, where one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Check out what ended up being the solution in my answer.  Maybe this could help you in the future.  Thanks as always, Eric.